# Windows XP SP1 with invalid key, upgrade to Windows XP SP3 with valid key

Tags: windows-xp, product-key

I have a Windows XP Professional SP1 system with an illegal key (not mine).

I need to get it to SP3 in order for it to handle the software I am trying to install; I have a valid key for Windows XP Professional with SP3.

I seem to remember having a problem with this once before, like the key for a higher SP3 version not working to activate an SP1 Windows.

What steps should I take so that the computer can upgrade to SP3 with the new valid key without formatting it, or screwing it up?

A good answer would show a definitive activation and upgrade path that is *sure* to work, as making the machine inoperable is not a risk I can take.

Comment: I've edited the question to include information from comments on an earlier answer.

Comment: +1 because the original poster is being **ethical** by trying to correct a licensing problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [Magical Jellybean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) to update the key. Then install SP3.

Comment: Have an upvote, because this is exactly what needs to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this same problem by using Microsoft's [Windows Product Key Update Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/help/genuine/product-key) - select Windows XP (also available for Windows 7), etc

Answer (score 0):

This web site may help you get those updates installed so that you can get up to the Service Pack 3 level:

Windiz Update
  http://www.windizupdate.com/

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**  This web site supports all web browsers except for Internet Explorer.  If you use Internet Explorer, you'll get an error indicating that your web browser is not supported.